# Does GetWriteWatch work with Memory-Mapped FIles?

Tags: windows

outI'm working with memory mapped files (MMF) with very large datasets (depending on the input file), where each file has ~50GB and there are around 40 files open at the same time. Of course this depends, I can also have smaller files, but I can also have larger files - so the system should scale itself.

The MMF is acting as a backing buffer, so as long as I have enough free memory there shoud occur no paging. The problem is that the windows memory manager and my application are two autonomous processes. In good conditions everything is working fine, but the memory manager obviously is too slow in conditions where I'm entering low memory conditions, the memory is full and then the system starts to page (which is good), but I'm still allocating memory, because I don't get any information about the paging.

In the end I'm entering a state where the system stalls, the memory manager pages and I'm allocating.

So I came to the point where I need to advice the memory manager, check current memory conditions and invoke the paging myself. For that reason I wanted to use the GetWriteWatch to inspect the memory region I can flush.

Interestingly the GetWriteWatch does not work in my situation, it returns a -1 without filling the structures. So my question is does GetWriteWatch work with MMFs?

Answer (score 1):

> Does GetWriteWatch work with Memory-Mapped Files?

I don't think so.

`GetWriteWatch` accepts memory allocated via `VirtualAlloc` function using `MEM_WRITE_WATCH`.

File mapping are mapped using `MapViewOfFile*` functions that do not have this flag.

Comment: That was my fear. Do you know a better way to find out which pages are dirty instead of using GetWriteWatch?

Comment: @msedi, I have no idea, sorry